# AEM/CQ: Capture each part of page path in an array

Tags: jstl, aem, depth

I have a CQ / AEM site.I am pretty new to AEM

I am doing a page depth function call.

```
<c:set var="pageDepth" value="<%= currentPage.getDepth() %>"/>
```

Path is

```
<c:set var="path" value="<%= properties.get("path", currentPage.getPath()) %>"/>
```

Path is

```
 /content/my-blueprint/homepage/subpage/subpage1
```

I want to capture each part of path in a data structure (array/linked list) like

array[0] should be content and array[2] should be homepage etc..

Is there a way I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the path on the / character.

You can do it java-style in the scriptlet:

`<c:set var="pathArray" value="<%= properties.get("path", currentPage.getPath()).split("/") %>"/>`

or JSTL-style:

`<c:set var="pathArray" value="${fn:split(path, '/')}"/>`

To access the array, you would do `${pathArray[2]}`